# iterating and looping in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this code using javascript. where i use for loop in evaluating the text box if it has content or none.

this is the code:

```
 function validateTable()
 {
 var rowCount = $('#mhTable >tbody >tr').length;
 //alert(rowCount);
 for(var ctr = 1; ctr <= rowCount; ctr++)
 {
    if( $('input[name^="process['+ctr+']"]').val() != '' )
    {
        continue;

    }
    else if( $('input[name^="process['+ctr+']"]').val() == '' )
    {
        messagealertManhourCheck("Error","Please fill out the form");
    }
}
SaveSavingsData();
}
```

my problem is when there are many textboxes and if one of the textbox do not have any content. it will still go in the function saveSavingsData();

but it must be error.

Answer (score 2):

```
function validateTable() {
    var rowCount = $('#mhTable >tbody >tr').length,
        hasErrors = false;
    for(var ctr = 1; ctr <= rowCount; ctr++) {
        if( $('input[name^="process['+ctr+']"]').val() == '' ) {
            messagealertManhourCheck("Error","Please fill out the form");
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    }
    if (!hasErrors) {
        SaveSavingsData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code, it will always execute the SaveSavingsData(), if you want to stop execute if a input value is '',you can:

```
function validateTable()
{
    var rowCount = $('#mhTable >tbody >tr').length;
    //alert(rowCount);
    for(var ctr = 1; ctr <= rowCount; ctr++)
    {
      if( $('input[name^="process['+ctr+']"]').val() != '' )
      {
        continue;

      }
      else
      {
        messagealertManhourCheck("Error","Please fill out the form");
        return;
      }
    }
    SaveSavingsData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `else` statement with `continue`, and you can use an additional variable for checking if there are any empty textboxes:

```
function validateTable()
{
    var rowCount = $('#mhTable >tbody >tr').length;
    var isValid = true;
    //alert(rowCount);
    for(var ctr = 0; ctr < rowCount; ctr++)//any reason your loop was starting from 1 ?? I changed it to 0
    {
       if( $('input[name^="process['+ctr+']"]').val() == '' )
       {
           isValid = false;
           messagealertManhourCheck("Error","Please fill out the form");
       }
    }
    if(isValid)
         SaveSavingsData();
}
```